# Filter two image collections by the same aqusition date in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to compare images aquired from two different sensors: MSI on board of Sentinel-2 and MODIS on board of Terra, using Google Earth Engine.
MODIS provides his own band of the parameter I am instered in at 500 km resolution  concentrantion meanwhile I created my own algorithm in Sentinel-2 at finer resolution.
I want to compare the results over a specific area but first I want to filter the two collections by selecting only images that were aquired approximately on the same date, it only matters the YYYY-MM-DD.
Specifically TERRA has a daily temporal resolution over the selected area while Sentinel-2 5 days. Basically I want to reduce the MODIS collection selecting only those images overlapping temporally with Sentinel-2.
Note that I will nead to map the results.
I don't have any idea on how to do it, I came across the function 'inner.Join' but I don't know how to use it.
I am not planning to merge them into one Image collection, I want to keep them separetely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tried this and somehow seems it works, could be a solution. If someone want to check it and see if it works here it is:
First I defined the date by doing .map over both  collections with the following code:

```
.map(function(image) {
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format("YYYY-MM-dd");
  date = ee.Date(date);
    return image.set('date', date);
  })
  ;
```

The code above adds an extra property 'date' in the format YYYY-MM-dd to the collections. I did it because it seems that if I only use 'system:time_start' it doesen't find any matching dates, perhaps due to different time of aquisition?

```
 var filterTimeEq = ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'date',
    rightField: 'date'
    });
    

    var simpleJoin = ee.Join.simple()
    var simpleJoinedCollection = simpleJoin.apply(first_coll, second_coll, filterTimeEq)
 

var collection= ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoinedCollection)
Map.addLayer(collection)
```